# How to get device account merged with contacts list

Tags: android, contacts, account

My app presents the device contact list for the user to select a contact.  However, I do not see the device login - the name & email used to sign in to the android store - in the contact list.

I've read other posts showing how I can get the device login from the system profile.  However, I'm trying to understand what prevents or allows that login info from getting added to the gmail account contacts list.

Ultimately, I want to use this info for the user to register his usage of my app.  With that, I intend to receive the user's name and email address (with his permission, of course).  Perhaps there's a better way to approach what I want.

Answer (score 0):

That account used to login to the device is the user's account. The contact list you are talking about are the user's contacts. If I were the user, I think it would be odd to have myself listed as one of my contacts...

It sounds like you already know how to get the information you want. I don't believe there's a "better" approach than simply doing that. You need to be more clear on why that is not a good approach or what about that approach needs to be improved.

Comment: Thanks, Jim, for your advise.  So, I'll continue with the path I'm on.  I didn't intend to say my approach isn't good, I was only asking if there's a better approach.  Sorry if that came across differently.  As for myself being in my contacts, mine ended up that way a long time ago for purposes of bcc.  However, I agree in general it would be of little use.